# create div with an inner div with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I've been looking for a way to create a div with a div inside to create a box with a header with javascript.

ie.

```
<div>title<div>content</div></div>
```

The code I have

```
function addpost() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "item";
  var t = document.createTextNode("title<div>content</div>");
  div.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("cannot be empty");
  } else {
   document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

The result that I have been getting ends up in the webpage. :(

```
title<div>content</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("myUL").innerHTML='<div>title<div>content</div></div>';`

Comment: just use .innerHTML = "your html" and insert in a div

Comment: Trying to make it dynamic. That would just erase my previous content right? I would like it to add on.

Comment: `document.getElementById("myUL").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", "<div>title<div>content</div></div>");`

Comment: I think I found what was wrong, let me know if my answer worked for you :)

Comment: I modified my answer. It fixes one more issue I found. Let me know if that is the result you wanted.

Comment: `innerHTML += 'whatever'` <- this will add content, not replace (sort of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function addpost() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "item";
  var t = document.createTextNode("title");
  div.appendChild(t);
  var x = document.createElement("div");
  var y = document.createTextNode("content");
  x.appendChild(y);
  div.appendChild(x);
  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st Problem:**

You forgot to include **inputValue** as a parameter in the function. You manually included the text to include with this line: `var t = document.createTextNode("title<div>content</div>");` when you should have done `var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);`

This code should work for you:

```
function addpost(inputValue) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "item";
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  div.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("cannot be empty");
  } else {
   document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(div);
  }
}
addpost("title<div>content</div>");
```

**2nd Problem**

You are inserting `"title<div>content</div>"` as text. This means the tags will not be considered as code, but will be escaped. To fix this, what you make `var t` another node, and include the text within `var t`.

This code should work for you:

```
   function addpost(titleInput, inputValue) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = "item";
      var t = document.createElement("div");
      t.id = "text";
      var t2 = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
      t.appendChild(t2);
      div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(titleInput));
      div.appendChild(t);
      if (inputValue === '') {
        alert("cannot be empty");
      } else {
       document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(div);
      }
    }
    addpost("title","content");
```

Comment: thanks for the help, however Baraka posted the first working response and the second way you submitted works. However, the first one didn't work :(. upvoted though since it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

For adding the content dynamically without deleting the content that was set there before, you also add it like this:

```
 div.innerElement = div.innerElement + "here comes the new stuff";
```